# Test is not running service mock promise (.then)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I have tried to create a mock of my `BoardService`. However, the `.then` function is not being run in the `controller` when running the test, but it's working fine when running the actual application.

Here is the test:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $q) {

    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    BoardController = $controller('BoardController', {
        $scope: scope,
        board: {
            id: 1,
            tasks: []
        },
        BoardService: {

            addTask: function(data) {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                defer.resolve(1);
                return defer.promise;
            }
        }
    });

}));

it("should add a new task", function() {

    scope.addTask(category, 'this is a new task');

    expect(scope.board.tasks.length).toBe(1);

});
```

And the controller function:

```
$scope.addTask = function(category, task) {

    BoardService.addTask({name: task, category: category.id, boardId: $scope.board.id}).then(function(task_id) {

        // Never reaches here

        $scope.board.tasks.push({id : task_id, name : task, category : category.id, board_id : $scope.board.id});

    });
}
```

Why is it never reaching the comment in the `.then` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After resolving the promise you need to trigger a digest-cycle for angular to pick up on it.

```
scope.addTask(category, 'this is a new task');
scope.$digest();
expect(scope.board.tasks.length).toBe(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

As we discussed on IRC: you need to call scope.$digest for the promise to fire.